# Referencing a board game rule book

Tags: citations

I'm writing a paper on a board game, 
[Labyrinth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labyrinth_(board_game)), and I need to use some parts of the rule book. How should I reference this? I'm using Harvard reference style.

EDIT: I hadn't notice this earlier.

What can be found in the start of the rule book is this:

> Author: Max J. Kobbert

And in the end, this:

> © 2007 Ravensburger Spieleverlag

EDIT 2: I found a link to the rule book. The real one contains for several more languages but the content is the same.

[Link to rule book](http://www.ravensburger.com/spielanleitungen/ecm/Spielanleitungen/Labyrinth_26448_GB.pdf)

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE! As a first guess, look up the copyright information in the rule book and cite it as a book. If none is available, find the relevant information (e.g. for a corporate author) from other sources

Comment: I have updated the question with some new found information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of referencing is to allow others to determine what you've referenced and to look it up in turn.

Harvard has tools for [citing multi-media formats](http://guides.is.uwa.edu.au/content.php?pid=43218&sid=318558), such as board games.

Inline: ([Rulebook] 1986).

Biblio: [Rulebook] 1986 *Labyrinth* (boardgame), Ravensburger.

Consult a full style guide and model off the nearest multi media work, for example, album liners to a CD.

Are you sure 2007 is really the date of the edition and not the printing?

(Kobbert 2007).

Kobbert, MJ 2007 '[Rulebook]' *Labyrinth* (boardgame), Ravensburger Spieleverlag.

Comment: Updated the question once again to provide all the information I have. I think why it is 2007 is because it's a new edition of the game. You can see there is different edition with different player tokens and slightly different pictures on the tiles, if you Google for some images.

Comment: If this is all you've got, then okay, but I strongly advise you to examine the physical object fully for edition information, so you can supply edition information with your citation.

Comment: I can't find anymore information except repeating information of what I already know, on the back.